# What is the return type of a constructor in java?

Tags: java, constructor, jvm, bytecode

As we know that we do not have to add any return type to a Java constructor.

```
class Sample{
  .....
  Sample(){
    ........
  }
}
```

In Objective C, if we create a constructor, it returns a pointer to its class. But it is not compulsory, I think.

```
AClass *anObject = [[AClass alloc] init];//init is the constructor with return type a pointer to AClass
```

Similarly, Is the constructor converted to a method which return a reference to its own class??

Like this:

```
class Sample{
    .....
    Sample Sample(){
      ........

      return this;
    }
}
```

Does the compiler add a return type a reference to same class to constructor?
What is happening to a constructor?
Any reference to study this?

#### EDIT:

Actually i want the answers to be at byte code level or JVM level or even below.

Comment: I believe constructors are special and not handled the same as normal method calls. For all intents and purposes though the "return type" is that of the containing type itself: although nothing is ever explicitly returned at the code level.

Comment: pls give me a reference to clarify my doubt

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Many have answered how constructors are defined in Java.

At the JVM level, static initialisers and constructors are methods which return void.  Static initialisers are static methods, however constructors use `this` and don't need to return anything.  This is because the caller is responsible for creating the object (not the constructor)

If you try to only create an object in byte code without calling a constructor you get a VerifyError. However on the oracle JVM you can use Unsafe.allocateInstance() to create an object without calling a constructor,

The static initialiser is called `<cinit>` which takes no arguments and the constructor is called `<init>`. Both have a void return type.

For the most part, this is hidden from the Java developer (unless they are generating byte code) however the only time you see these "methods" in stack traces (though you can't see a return type)

Comment: i like this.This type of answers is what i want...which are at the JVM level.....pls giv me a refernce for me to study more

Comment: @peter what does the "c" in "cinit" stand for?

Comment: @Geek Short for "Class INITializer".

Answer (score 4):

While constructors are similar to methods, they are not methods. They have no return type, are not inherited, and cannot be hidden or overridden by subclasses.

Constructors are invoked by class instance-creation expressions (basically, the use of `new`), by explicit invocation from other constructors (using `this(...)` or `super(...)` syntax), and by the string concatenation operator. There is no other way to invoke a constructor (in particular, they cannot be invoked like other methods).

See [Section 8.8 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.8) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the constructor converted to a method which return a reference to its own class??

**No** but yes, if it is specified to do so.

> Does compiler add a return type a reference to same class to constructor ??

**No** it does not

> What is happening to a constructor??

It is the method, which runs when the object is created. Typically, by using "new" keyword. It Might perform some preliminary task, or return something or assign some values during construction.

> Any reference to study this.??

- [http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2000/jw-1013-constructors.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20130626185312/http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2000/jw-1013-constructors.html)
- [http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-constructors](https://web.archive.org/web/20120307135554/http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-constructors)

Answer (score 2):

Constructors are similar to methods except that they use the name of the class and have no return type. The whole purpose of using constructors is to create an object (an instance of a class) and allocate it (via `new` keyword) in the memory (the heap) and also initialize any fields if available.

Comment: @sonuthomas It is new, but you cannot call new without the constructor.

Comment: Ted Hopp gave me this `Constructors are invoked by class instance-creation expressions (basically, the use of new), by explicit invocation from other constructors (using this(...) or super(...) syntax), and by the string concatenation operator.`

Comment: @sonuthomas still you need to use the constructor after the `new` keyword, and of course you can use `this()` or `super()` inside that constructor.

Comment: @praetoriandroid you are right! however, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are invoked via the special java keyword `new`, which creates (and initializes) an object of the specified concrete type.

I suppose you could say the combination of `new` and the chosen constructor "returns" an object, which in java is of course a pointer under the covers

Answer (score 0):

Constructor returns the class reference of the class for which its being called.E.g.-

```
class A {
    int x;
    A(int a) {
        x = a;
    }
}
class B {
    public static void main(String asd[]) {
        A a = new A(4);
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Here after calling the constructor `A(...)`, this constructor will return the reference of type of class `A` to caller( i.e. `A a = new A(4)` ).

Comment: At the source level, what you say is correct-enough, however the accepted answer (Peter Lawrey's) includes details of the underlying VM model as the questioner requested.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the constructor is corresponding class type.

```
package com.ie.test;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class a {
    public  a() {
        super();
        System.out.println("*** no-arg constructor ***");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Constructor[] constructors =  a.class.getConstructors();

        for (Constructor constructor:constructors) {

            int i =  constructor.getModifiers();
            AnnotatedType annotatedType =  constructor.getAnnotatedReturnType();
            System.out.println("***********Returntype *******"+annotatedType.getType());
            System.out.println("*******constructor *****"+Modifier.toString(i));
        }

        Method[] methods =  a.class.getDeclaredMethods();

        for (Method method:methods) {
            int i =  method.getModifiers();
            //  Class c =  method.getReturnType();
            AnnotatedType annotatedType =  method.getAnnotatedReturnType();
            System.out.println("***********Returntype *******"+annotatedType.getType());
            //   System.out.println(c);
            System.out.println("*******methods*******"+Modifier.toString(i));
        }
    }

    public int m1() {
        System.out.println("***************");
        return 0;
    }
}
```