# What is the return type of a constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, constructor

I have asked this question for Java on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8868117/350601) link

I got some answers in java.Now i want to know it in C#.

As we know the we do not have to add any return type to a C# constructor.

```
class Sample{
  .....
  Sample(){
    ........
  }
}
```

In Objective C, if we create a constructor, it returns a pointer to its class. But it is not compulsory, I think.

```
AClass *anObject = [[AClass alloc] init];//init is the constructor with return type a pointer to AClass
```

Similarly, Is the constructor converted to a method which return a reference to its own class??

Like this:

```
class Sample{
    .....
    Sample Sample(){
      ........

      return this;
    }
}
```

Does the compiler add a return type a reference to same class to constructor?
What is happening to a constructor?
Any reference to study this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming) says that `c'tor doesn't have an explicit return type`. I'm also curious to know about implicit return type.

Comment: Constructors dont return any thing not even void.
look at this [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/clr/thread/24584856-990d-4613-bfc1-f845414e36ed)

Comment: Regarding ObjC, I believe alloc returns the pointer to the memory blob. `init` just initializes needed variables and checks for memory allocation failure.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

According to the *C# 4.0 Language Specification*, section 1.6:

> Instances of classes are created using the `new` operator, which allocates memory for a new instance, invokes a constructor to initialize the instance, and returns a reference to the instance.

It is the `new` operator who is responsible of allocating memory, passing a reference of the newly allocated object to the constructor and then returning a reference to the instance. This mechanism is also explained in section 7.6.10.1:

> The run-time processing of an *object-creation-expression* of the form
>   `new T(A)`, where `T` is *class-type* or a *struct-type* and `A` is an optional
>   *argument-list*, consists of the following steps:
>
> - If `T` is a *class-type*:
>
>   - A new instance of class `T` is allocated. If there is not enough
>       memory available to allocate the new instance, a
>       `System.OutOfMemoryException` is thrown and no further steps are
>       executed.
>   - All fields of the new instance are initialized to their default
>       values (§5.2).
>   - The instance constructor is invoked according to the
>       rules of function member invocation (§7.5.4). A reference to the newly
>       allocated instance is automatically passed to the instance constructor
>       and the instance can be accessed from within that constructor as `this`.
> - […]

This would mean that the constructor *per se* has no return type (`void`).

Comment: +1 Good explanation. You can see this behaviour also when creating your own new operator in C++ and look at the default implementation. :-)

Comment: @sonuthomas: You don't have to accept the highest rated answer, just choose the one that helped you the most or answered your question best (in your opinion). See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)

Comment: @sonuthomas Accept the answer which is likly to help you and other users most.

Answer (score 19):

InBetween's answer is correct. I too disagree with what was discussed in the MSDN forum. If we look at a very simple code sample like the one below:

```
void Main()
{
   var a = new A();
   var message = a.GetAs();
}

public class A {

    private readonly string someAs;

    public A()
    {
        someAs = "AaaaaAAAAAaaAAAAAAAaa";
        return;
    }

    public String GetAs()
    {
        return someAs;
    }
}
```

and the corresponding IL:

```
IL_0000:  newobj      UserQuery+A..ctor
IL_0005:  stloc.0     
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     
IL_0007:  callvirt    UserQuery+A.GetMessage

A.GetMessage:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldfld       UserQuery+A.someAs
IL_0006:  ret         

A..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  ldarg.0     
IL_0007:  ldstr       "AaaaaAAAAAaaAAAAAAAaa"
IL_000C:  stfld       UserQuery+A.someAs
IL_0011:  ret
```

then it becomes immediately clear, that the .ctor returns `void`. (This can also been seen easily if you *try* to return something from the constructor, i.e. if you do something like `public A() { return this; }` the compiler will complain and say something like "Since A() returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression.")

Further: You can see that this expression `new A()` gets translated to the following IL: `newobj      UserQuery+A..ctor`. The "Common Language Infrastructure Reference" says the following about `newobj` (section 4.20):

> The newobj instruction allocates a new instance of the class associated with constructor and initializes all the fields in the new instance to 0 (of the proper type) or null as appropriate. It then calls the constructor with the given arguments along with the newly created instance. After the constructor has been called, the now initialized object reference is pushed onto the stack.

(By way of comparison with Objective-C: new/newobj is the analog to the `alloc` message and the constructor the analog to the `init`message.)

So it really is the `new` operator that returns a reference to the newly constructed object, not the constructor itself.

Comment: Look a level further below the IL, and it behaves much like it would if it called an method that returned on object, though at that level "return type" becomes vaguer, but then just which conceptual level is the correct one?

Comment: @JonHanna: Looking at the compiled x86, the constructor code behaves much like a void instance method in both IL and x86.

Comment: @Joren: No wonder. The CLI reference states: "Constructors shall be _instance methods_, defined via a special form of method contract, which defines the method contract as a constructor for a particular object type." (Section 8.9.6.6, emphasis added by me)

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how you look at it.

"Return type" is as much conceptual as anything else.

At the level of the semantics in which C# expresses a programmers intent, constructors don't have return types. They don't even have `void`. They've no more got a return type than you do.

The IL those constructors will be compiled to, have a return type of `void`.

If you invoke a `ConstructorInfo` you get an object of the type in question (though the type of the return on that invoke is `object` and you have to cast to the type concerned).

The closest thing to a concrete meaning to return is the details of how the stack gets manipulated by the constructor being called. Here though you could argue that while a reference type "returns" a reference of the appropriate type, since it places the value in the stack, a value type doesn't since it manipulates the values already present on the stack. Or you could just argue that both are implementation details, and not really answering the question at all.

"Doesn't have a return type" is probably the most "C#ish" of the above ways of looking at the question.

Comment: The `new` operator places the value on the stack, not the constructor. "Return type" is a pretty easily definable thing.

Comment: @AdamRobinson Only at the C#ish level in which the constructor doesn't have a return type, and the new operator exists. The other ways of looking at it aren't wrong, so I included them, but I do agree it's the most useful way to view it while coding C#.

Comment: The `new` operator exists in `IL` as `newobj`. Take a look at the IL (you can see an example in afrischke's answer). There is no returning going on, and the constructor doesn't place a reference on the stack; the `newobj` operator does.

Comment: @AdamRobinson and if I invoke a `ConstructorInfo`? Yes, I know it's not the same, but surely that I don't have to think about it is the point?

Comment: ... and the IL constructor does have a return type, it has `void`.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't have a return type at the IL layer (it does, as you say; it's `void`); I'm taking issue with your sixth paragraph, which says that the constructor places the reference on the stack, when it does not.

Comment: @AdamRobinson Ah. Well, that was me trying to word things so as to find a way that you *could* say it returns something though I wouldn't really agree. It can be hard to express opinions you don't agree with well. I open and close with "doesn't have a return type" for a reason :)