# If constructor is a method, that doesnt return anything why is there no return type as void? C#

Tags: c#

In C#, if consturctors are basucally methods that dont return anything, why dont they have a return type as void? since void is a return type that denotes the same that nothing is returned.

Comment: It's just the way the language syntax is designed. And logically, they *do* return something: a new instance.

Comment: [What is the return type of a constructor in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893959/what-is-the-return-type-of-a-constructor-in-c)

Comment: @MatthewWatson they actually don't return anything, hence void. It is the `new` operator which is responsible of allocation memory, creating instance and returning the reference the to instance. See, @IlyaIvanov 's link for further reference.

Answer (score 4):

If the return type was (in language/syntax terms) always "void", what would be the point of saying "void"? It would be redundant, and could only serve as something to get wrong. If "void" is the only valid option, why would we need to tell the compiler? Why not just omit it completely?

Answer (score 2):

It is a language construct to differentiate a constructor from ordinary method calls.

However, at the IL level (and as you pointed out), the constructor is nothing but a void method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to prevent class users to call it arbitrarily like:

```
SomeClass myClass = new SomeClass();
myClass.SomeClass(); 
...
myClass.SomeClass();
```

Comment: Whether it is callable in that way is largely unrelated to the declared return type