# Aspect oriented design pattern Cuckoo's Egg in C# using PostSharp

Tags: c#, design-patterns, postsharp, aop

I am trying to implement AO design pattern Cuckoo's egg in C# using *Postsharp*.

The idea of this design pattern is as it's name states, to replace existing object by some other object. In *AspectJ* it is done by something like this:

```
public aspect MyClassSwapper {
  public pointcut myConstructors(): call(MyClass.new());
  Object around(): myConstructors() {
      return new AnotherClass();
  }
}

public class AnotherClass extends MyClass {
    . . .
}
```

I am novice to Postsharp so I want to ask, if there are tools in Postsharp which enables to do something similar - override the return value of constructor of base class and return the object of subclass?

Answer (score 0):

While *PostSharp* allows you to apply [OnMethodBoundaryAspect](http://doc.postsharp.net/content/T_PostSharp_Aspects_OnMethodBoundaryAspect) to constructor, you still will not be able to replace the object instance returned. In fact, constructors in C# do not return values. There are relevant questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788312/why-do-constructors-not-return-values) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893959/what-is-the-return-type-of-a-constructor-in-c).

Another way to implement the Cuckoo's egg pattern would be to intercept the methods of your original class and instead call the appropriate methods on another class instance. In this case, `AnotherClass` doesn't even have to derive from `MyClass` or you can delegate different methods to different replacement classes.

The example implementation of the [MethodInterceptionAspect](http://doc.postsharp.net/content/T_PostSharp_Aspects_MethodInterceptionAspect) implementing the pattern can look like this:

```
[Serializable]
[MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Method, Inheritance = MulticastInheritance.None)]
public class MyClassSwapperAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect, IInstanceScopedAspect
{
    private readonly Type cuckooType;

    [NonSerialized] private object cuckooEgg;

    public MyClassSwapperAttribute(Type cuckooType)
    {
        this.cuckooType = cuckooType;
    }

    private MyClassSwapperAttribute()
    {
        // this creates an "empty" aspect instance applied on the cuckoo's egg itself
    }

    public object CreateInstance(AdviceArgs adviceArgs)
    {
        if (adviceArgs.Instance.GetType() == cuckooType)
            return new MyClassSwapperAttribute();

        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    public void RuntimeInitializeInstance()
    {
        if (this.cuckooType == null)
            return;

        // for each instance of the target class we create a new cuckoo's egg instance
        this.cuckooEgg = Activator.CreateInstance(cuckooType);
    }

    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        if (this.cuckooEgg == null)
        {
            base.OnInvoke(args);
        }
        else
        {
            // delegate the method invocation to the cuckoo's egg, that derives from the target class
            args.ReturnValue = args.Method.Invoke(this.cuckooEgg, args.Arguments.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation requires `AnotherClass` to derive from `MyClass` and you have to apply the attribute on the `MyClass` itself, for example like this:

```
[MyClassSwapper(typeof (AnotherClass))]
class MyClass
{
    // ...
}
```