# Call instance method inline after New statement

Tags: vb.net

How can i convert this code to VB.net

```
public void SetBooks(IEnumerable<Book> books)
    {
        if (books == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("books");

        new System.Xml.Linq.XDocument(books).Save(_filename);
    }
```

in http://converter.telerik.com/ it says:

```
Public Sub SetBooks(books As IEnumerable(Of Book))
        If books Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("books")
        End If
        New System.Xml.Linq.XDocument(books).Save(_filename)
End Sub
```

But visual studio says **"Syntax error."** because of **"New"**

What is the **keyword** for this situation, i searched on **Google** but no result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot initialize an object and use it in one statement in VB.NET (as opposed to C#). You need two:

```
Dim doc = New System.Xml.Linq.XDocument(books)
doc.Save(_filename)
```

In C# the constructor [returns the instance of the created object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8894286/284240), in VB.NET not.

Comment: For completeness: you could avoid the variable (C# doesn't need one, so why should VB.NET?) by using `With New System.Xml.Linq.XDocument(books)` / `.Save(_filename)` / `End With`.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, you can do it in one line with the Call keyword

```
Call (New System.Xml.Linq.XDocument(books)).Save(_filename)
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't know about this. I realize this is an old Q&A, but I'm so glad I found it as it's enabling me to "clean up" a bunch of code.