# Do all methods return something

Tags: c#, methods, constructor

**Statement:**

"all methods return something".

I read in study books that "all methods return something" and my teacher confirmed this.

A method can return the following things:

1. Void
2. Any other object

**Questions**

These questions came up to me:

- "Is void something or is it just a keyword for the compiler"
- "Is an constructor a method"?

  - "If a constructor is an method does it return something.

This is not duplicated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893959/what-is-the-return-type-of-a-constructor-in-c) because my question is not specific about constructor returning but about the statement above.

**Questions workout**

- When a constructor **is not** a method this statement would be true.

  - Because methods return void or object.
- But when the constructor **is** a method does it return something, if not this statement would  be false.

  - Because the constructor is a method but does not return anything.
- When void is not something that is returned but just a keyword for the compiler to now that it is not returning anything than this hole statement would be false.

  - Because this will mean that methods can return nothing because void is not something

There are a lot of questions in this question but I ask them in one because all these are in one cohesion to this statement "all methods return something". So is true true?

Comment: _Hint_: `MyType instance = new MyType();`

Comment: @TimSchmelter said it.

Comment: Spoiler alert: The constructor returns `void`. `new` returns the instance.

Comment: Also, what of methods containing infinite loops? They don't return anything.

Comment: @Tim: or `new` returns the instance which had been created and initialized with the given constructor, which itself didn't return anything ... ;-)

Comment: Is returning void returning something? For me this had always been a syntax oddity coming from C.

Comment: To answer the question *"Is this statement false: All methods return something"*. I'd say it false. `void` isn't really a *return type*, more of a *"we have to put something there so the compiler knows that we return nothing"* kind a thing. I think this is more of a philosophical question like method vs. function.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger [*The void type, in several programming languages derived from C and Algol68, is the type for the result of a function that returns normally, but does not provide a result value to its caller*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_type). Although it does not produce a *value*, `void` itself is a type, it is the type of values which produce no value :)

Comment: the constructor is called after the memory is allocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is an constructor a method

Yes.

> if a constructor is an method does it return something?

*Yes*, `void`, according to the IL (to test this, make a small C# app, compile it, and open the EXE with `ildasm`):

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void  .ctor() cil managed
```

*No* according to the C# language specification.

Comment: Where is mentioned that a constructor is a method?

Comment: @TimSchmelter `.method`