# Are class constructors void by default?

Tags: c#, void, class-constructors

I have been reading on class constructors in C#. Examples are showing overloaded class contructors. And all of them do not have a `void` keyword and neither they have a return value..

e.g.

```
public Class myClass
{
  public myClass()
  {

  }

  public myClass(int id)
  {

  }
//other class memeber go here...
}
```

1) So is it correct to say C# constructors are `void` by default?

2) Does the same applies to Java as well?

Comment: For constructor return types, see:

C#     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893959/what-is-the-return-type-of-a-constructor-in-c

java   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868117/what-is-the-return-type-of-a-constructor-in-java

Comment: @mcalex thanks. That's helpful :) >According to the C# 4.0 Language Specification, section 1.6:

`Instances of classes are created using the new operator, which allocates memory for a new instance, invokes a constructor to initialize the instance, and returns a reference to the instance.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no,  they are constructors,  if anything, you can think of them as returning an object of the class they are from.  But, they aren't normal method/functions

Comment: For other methods if we don't have void modifier then we must return something.. But class constructor (methods) don't follow the same norm although it's returning the object of the class internally, rather the returning process is wrapped/hidden within the instantiation. Am I in the right track then? Thanks :)

Comment: well,  the keyword new allocates the memory for the object, the constructor takes that memory and....constructs the object, and then returns the constructed instance.   so var x = new myClass("stuff");

Comment: Excellent @Keith. I got it.

Comment: constructors work with the `new` keyword to do the return stuff.  As Keith said, they're not normal methods.  Just think of them as constructors

Answer (score 2):

No Constructors implicitly return class type same as java also.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors have no return type and do not return anything, it's not a method. From C# language specification 4.0:

> An instance constructor is a member that implements the actions
>   required to initialize an instance of a class.  Instance constructors are declared using 
>   constructor-declarations.

*attributes opt   constructor-modifiers opt   constructor-declarator   constructor-body*

> A constructor is declared like a method with no return type and the
>   same name as the containing class

There is no return type here.

Constructor is invoked through the `new` operator, which is the one, that returns an instance of an object.

Comment: I think constructors invoked through () after class name. not new keyword