# C# Constructor returning pointer on other object

Tags: c#, pointers, object, constructor

I would like to know if it's possible that a constructor is able return a pointer on an already instantiated object form the same class?
For instance:

```
    Class Example
    {
            private static Example A = null

            public Example()
            {
                    if (RefTrace == null)
                    {
                            //Here is the initialization of all attributes
                             A = this;
                    }
                      else
                            return A; //To return pointer on already existing instance.
            }


    }
```

**EDIT :**
This is just the idea, i know that it doesn't work. But I would like to know if there is a way to achieve this?

Comment: why don't you try it out and see for yourself?

Comment: I try and it doesnt work. This is just to show why i am trying to achieve

Comment: Constructors don't return anything.

Comment: you can have something like this - in Javascript ;) - in C# a constructor will create you a new object, but the obvious solution is writing a static method   ;)

Comment: How about making the constructor private and have a public static method like `public static Example GetExample()` where you put your "decide if new object should be instanciated or stored value should be returned" logic in?

Comment: You can use a static factory method on the class to do something like that. Make the constructor private if you want to make this to be the only way of constructing the instance.

Comment: Yes Corak that might work

Comment: Just make sure, for all of our sakes, that you declare that instance that will be being returned as volatile.

Comment: Ok i will be careful

Comment: @Alexandre M. Even if a constructor would return the class instance your example is wrong because if RefTrace is null you don't return anything. "else" has to be removed. What is RefTrace  even supposed to be? You had to check the static value A and if it's null to create a new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to implement is a Singleton object. You can read about Singleton pattern here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx.

Sample code:

```
public class Singleton
{
   private static Singleton instance;

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
     {
        if (instance == null)
      {
         instance = new Singleton();
      }
     return instance;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: No need for that silly check, that's what the static constructor is for. We're a dozen or two years past the good ol C++ days!

Comment: Also some (me included) see *Singleton* as an **anti-pattern** ([here is a nice example](https://molecularmusings.wordpress.com/2011/11/11/singleton-is-an-anti-pattern/))

Comment: @Random Dev
That isn't "a" example. It's a much too long article about a game engine where in many use cases singletons MAY be bad.

Comment: @Blindy I'm trying to transform some windows to singletons. I can't use a static constructor because they contain user controls and "InitializeComponent()" doesn't work for a static object, too. Maybe I have to store the instance outside the class but I think this is complicated thanks to 3rd party library for the main menu that seems to only call the constructor...

Comment: You most definitely can create your static instance and have that `InitializeComponent()` call work, though, again, I cannot emphasize enough just how absolutely dreadful your code base sounds. Do not do this. Use proper patterns (MVVM) to help guide you.

Answer (score 0):

From the [C# language specification 5.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) it says that:

> A constructor is declared like a method with no return type and the same name as the containing class.

This is also mentioned in other question/answers, i.e.: [Are class constructors void by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14949621/700926)

As mentioned already in this thread, it looks like you are trying to make use of the Singleton pattern. Jon Skeet has a [good blog post](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx) on various variants - I prefer his implementation with `Lazy<T>`.

Comment: I will take a look, I have a lack of terminology. Singleton is, indeed, what i was looking for. Thanks